# Docusign API: Live, then testing, back to live?

Tags: php, rest, docusignapi

Let us say I have taken an app live. I make some changes to code on MY side that need testing. Is it as simple as changing my configuration files to point at demo and account-d? Is there more to it? Is it even necessary?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, this is pretty much a configuration issue. Need to update all the OAuth information like clientSecret, RSA Key, userId, accountId (depending if you use JWT or Auth Code Grant) as well as other things that may be different like templateId or any other configuration information. And correct, it's account-d.docusign.com vs. account.docusign.com as well.

Lastly, it's possible that there are features/functionality between the developer account (where everything is free) and the production environment (where it depends on your plans and some features require an additional premium).

Some customers have two environments that they integrate with as they have their own test/UAT env and they'll leave that one all the time pointing to the DocuSign development (account-d) where they can test either changes in the DocuSign integration or any other changes in their own app.